# Files on ssd frequently get corrupted

Tags: ssd

On my second SSD, files frequently get corrupted. I usually store a lot of images files, and read them frequently (for machine learning tasks). But very frequently, single files become corrupted, and I cannot read them anylonger.

I have no issues on my main ssd, only on my secondary ssd. I checked temperatures, but they look fine.

Comment: Check smart information about the disk. For example see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1

Comment: It might be related to the file system you use in combination with being insufficiently careful when removing the drive. The file system likely should be repaired already.